# Calling a method on a new object in Java without parentheses: order of operations violation?

Tags: java, parsing, operator-precedence

According to [this table of Java operator precedence and associativity](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php), member access has higher precedence than the `new` operator.

However, given a class `myClass` and a non-static member function `myFunction`, the following line of code is valid:

`new myClass().myFunction();`

If `.` is evaluated before `new`, how can this line be executed? In other words, why aren't parentheses required?

`(new myClass()).myFunction();`

My guess is that since `()` shares precedence with `.`, the `myClass()` is evaluated first, and so the compiler knows even before evaluating the `new` keyword that the `myClass` constructor with zero parameters is being called. However, this still seems to imply that the first line should be identical to `new (myClass().myFunction());`, which is *not* the case.

Comment: That table is not a normative reference. You can't cite it as evidence.

Comment: @EJP Well, I realize it's not perfect, but it seemed sufficiently trustworthy. Other precedence-tables seem to indicate the same thing or leave out `.` entirely.

Comment: You can't have it both ways. Either it is perfect and 100% trustworthy or you can't cite it as evidence. The fact that it isn't normative means that it isn't 100% trustworthy *ipso facto.* Same applies to 'other precedence-tables', including as a matter of fact the one in the Java Tutorial. The one and only normative reference is the [Java Language Specification, Chapter 18](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html).

Comment: @EJP So you're saying that only the language spec should *ever* be used as reference material? I realize that only the language spec is *definitive*, but I don't see why that makes others *useless*. Would you, for instance, object if I made reference to another SO question and answer?

Comment: Don't put words into my mouth. You know what I said. You can't cite a third party website as evidence for the operator precedence in Java. You can't cite an SO answer either unless *it* cites or quotes from a normative reference. In this case it is obvious that it is the 3rd party site that is wrong. I don't know why we're even discussing it.

Comment: @EJP Okay, I misunderstood. I'm only "putting words in your mouth" because I'm trying to better understand what you're saying (and at this point why you're being such a jerk about it). The statement "you can't cite it as evidence" seems to imply that it's not valid as a reference source. So are you saying that it's fine to use non-normative references, but not okay to reference them in SO questions and answers?

Comment: 'Non-normative' *means* 'not valid as a reference source'. I have made no statement about using such sources in your daily work one way or the other, and I will not have words put into my mouth about it. I will add that in several decades on the Internet and its predecessors, I have observed that whenever a question starts 'so you are saying' the answer is invariably 'no'.

Comment: @EJP Weirdly enough, I reread this discussion every so often, and every time it boggles my mind. I'm not sure why we had such a hard time communicating, but I wonder if it's largely because I really don't know what you meant by "cite it as evidence." This isn't a court of law; I wasn't trying to prove that Java behaves (or should behave) in a certain way. I was simply making a genuine effort to understand a part of the language that I found confusing, and I used the link to explain why I was confused.

Comment: Yes, it's possible that I could have learned the answer by reading the language spec, but language specs are pretty dense, so I generally prefer to turn to Stack Overflow. Since this is one of my top-voted questions, it appears other people found the question at least somewhat intriguing; I'm still not sure why your reaction was so negative. (You also "put words in" my mouth as well, since I didn't bring up using non-reference sources in my daily work, but you, as far as I can tell from your last comment, implied that I did make some comment about your stance on that.)

Comment: As a side note, I also don't understand your equation of "non-normative" with "not valid as a reference source." In general, I don't think I understand any of your points about which sources are acceptable to use in which contexts. I am not a "language lawyer," as the phrase goes; at the time of asking the question, I was just a student who happened to be in a compiler class that (for some reason) used Java as the example language to be compiled.

Comment: Finally, from Jack's answer, you can see that the problem is in fact not one of precedence at all; there appears to be no error in the precedence table I cited (again, though, I'm not a language lawyer), so your statement that "In this case it is obvious that it is the 3rd party site that is wrong" was in fact not correct.

Comment: 'Non-normative' and 'not valid as a reference source' mean exactly the same thing. The JLS is the only normative reference here, *and therefore* the only valid reference source. No mystery. The JLS section I cited shows clearly that `new` and `.` have the *same* precedence, in which case left-to-right evaluation order applies.

Comment: @user207421 You seem to be repeating the same things you said 6 years ago; I'm not sure what that adds to the discussion. I also do not understand why you say that reference sources must be "normative".

Comment: Reference sources must be normative because otherwise they have no status and cannot be relied on, and this question is a perfect example. You have quoted a third-party source which is incorrect and you are asking why what it says is so. It isn't, and the normative reference says so. I'm saying the same thing I said six years ago, or now eight years ago, because it's still true, and I will continue saying it until you understand. There is no other rational course of action open to me.

Comment: @user207421 Repeating the statements with the same phrasing, with the expectation that I'll suddenly understand them when I didn't before, doesn't seem like a rational course of action at all.

Comment: @user207421 ...so you argued with me for ... (checks dates)... eight years, then, when I pointed out you were just repeating the same claim about what constitutes a "reference source", you decided to have the question closed? I guess that's at least different from continuing to repeat yourself.

Comment: @KyleStrand I vote to reopen since I had exactly the same question last night https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73348682/how-to-correctly-read-the-operator-precedence-in-new-java-io-filetiger-txt-t You may also want to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 47):

This is because of how the [grammar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) of Java language is defined. Precedence of operators comes into play just when the same lexical sequence could be parsed in two different ways but this is not the case.

Why?

Because the allocation is defined in:

```
Primary: 
  ...
  new Creator
```

while method call is defined in:

```
Selector:
  . Identifier [Arguments]
  ...
```

and both are used here:

```
Expression3: 
  ...
  Primary { Selector } { PostfixOp }
```

so what happens is that

```
new myClass().myFunction();
```

is parsed as

```
         Expression
             |
             |
    ---------+--------
    |                |
    |                |
  Primary        Selector
    |                |
    |                |
 ---+---            ...
 |     |
new   Creator
```

So there is no choice according to priority because the `Primary` is reduced before. Mind that for the special situation like

```
new OuterClass.InnerClass()
```

the class name is actually parsed before the `new` operator and there are rules to handle that case indeed. Check the grammar if you like to see them.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn't it should be: `new OuterClass.NestedClass()` in the last example?
I think you intended to mention 'static' nested class.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with the conclusion drawn from Jack's diagram.  When a grammar is written its nonterminals and structure are designed to implement the precedence and associativity of the language being described.  That's why the classic BNF for expressions introduces the "term" and "factor" nonterminals - to enforce the normal multiplication before addition precedence of arithmetic.

So the fact that "Primary -> new Creator" and "Expression -> Primary Selector" in the grammar means that "new Creator" is at a higher precedence level than "Primary Selector".

It seems to me that the grammar is evidence that the Java operator precedence and associativity table is incorrect.

Comment: It seems the specific premise in Jack's answer with which you disagree is "Precedence of operators comes into play just when the same lexical sequence could be parsed in two different ways". And indeed some grammars may be ambiguous as to order of operations, and may have a precedence table *in addition to* the grammar specification itself.

Comment: But it appears that you are correct that this is *not* the case for Java, because [Chapter 15 of the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html) says: "Precedence among operators is managed by a hierarchy of grammar productions. The lowest precedence operator is the arrow of a lambda expression (->), followed by the assignment operators." Your answer would be improved by citing this quote as evidence.

Comment: (I realize this quote is from a newer revision of the spec, since when I asked this question lambdas hadn't been introduced in Java yet.)