# Android: call a method from an AsyncTask

Tags: android

I want to call a method called getHoroscope() from an AsyncTask, from another class, I'm trying this

```
String sentence, signo="geminis";
sentence = new ExtendedActivity.Parse().getHoroscope("daily",signo);
```

But I get error "`ExtendedActivity is not an enclosing class`".
Can you help me?

My ExtendedActivity:

```
public class ExtendedActivity extends BaseActivity {
(...)
public class Parse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ExtendedActivity.this);


        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String option, type, dat, site="", description="", s="";;

            //get the user option
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            option = extras.getString("OPTION");
            type = extras.getString("TYPE");

            description = getHoroscope(type, option);

            return description;
        }


        public String getHoroscope(String type, String option){
            String description="", site;
            (...)
        }
     }
```

Comment: You are creating an object of ExtendedActivity and trying to access statically a method from Parse () class. Either, declare Parse and getHoroscope static or create an object of Parse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is not an enclosing class Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252727/is-not-an-enclosing-class-java)

Comment: Where u are calling `AsyncTask.execute` ?:

Answer (score 0):

You cand o it:

`new ExtendedActivity().new Parse().getHoroscope();`

or:

```
public class ExtendedActivity {
    public static class Parse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String description = "";

            description = getHoroscope();

            return description;
        }


        public static String getHoroscope() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like that: `new ExtendedActivity.Parse().getHoroscope();`